# What is the 'Srand' command equivalent in omnet++?

Tags: random, omnet++

I have a project in omnet platform and i am generating random numbers, lets say between 0-100. Everytime i run the simulation the randomly generated numbers become same. For example again, the first generated one is 32, second is 75 and so on. In second simulation the order and the generated numbers are same. I know that srand() is not compatible with omnet++ so i need help about finding an equivalent command. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent of `srand()` in `OMNeT++`. 
Generating the same sequence of number by `OMNeT++` [random number generator](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:sim-lib:random-number-generators) is fully intentional. Between others, it guarantees that the run of simulation  will be repeatable.
Moreover, generate random values will be different during another run. 

One can check this by adding the following line to `omnetpp.ini`:

```
repeat = 10
```

and then will turn out, that random values for `run=0` are different from values for `run=1`, `run=2` etc.